# Flutter graphql show actual request

Tags: flutter, graphql, flutter-graphql, graphql-flutter

I'm using [flutter_graphql](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter/install) and keep getting exception ***OperationException(linkException: ResponseFormatException(originalException: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1), )^ graphqlErrors: []),***

Is there a way to show the actual request sent?
Want to see in console the actual request passed

**Client**

```
class GraphqlClient {
  static String _token;
  static final String serverUrl =
      GlobalConfiguration().getString(Config.GRAPHQL_URL);

  static final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
     serverUrl,
  );

  static final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(getToken: () async {
    final SharedPrefsRepository _sharedPrefsRepository =
        SharedPrefsRepository();
    String accountKey = await _sharedPrefsRepository.getAccountKey();
    String sessionKey= await _sharedPrefsRepository.getSessionKey();
    _token = 'Bearer $accountKey, Bearer $sessionKey';
    debugPrint('token '+_token);
    return _token ?? '';
  });

  static final Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);

  static ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> initializeClient() {
    debugPrint('link '+link.toString());
    final policies = Policies(
      fetch: FetchPolicy.networkOnly,
    );
    
    final ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient>(
      GraphQLClient(
        cache: GraphQLCache(store: HiveStore()),
        link: link,
        defaultPolicies: DefaultPolicies(
          watchQuery: policies,
          query: policies,
          mutate: policies,
        ),
      ),
    );
    return client;
  }
}
```

**Request**

```
Query(
            options: QueryOptions(
              document: gql(DashboardGraphQL.accountDetailsQuery),
              operationName: 'AccountDetails',
            ),
```

**Query**

```
static const String accountDetailsQuery = """
      query AccountDetails {
    accountDetails {
      ... on AccountDetails {
        ibanList {
          accountId
          bicCode
          iban
        }
        accountType
        accountNumber
        accountNumberShort
        accountId
        ruid
        companyId
        accountDataOpened
        email
        mobile
        baseCurrency
        balanceInBaseCurrency
        lastTransactionDate
      }

      ... on ResponseErrors {
        errors {
          message
          code
          displayMessage

          ... on InternalError {
            message
            code
            displayMessage
            context
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
      """
```

Comment: i think you need to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create a Link that logs every request you sent and then concat it with your Link

```
class LoggerLink extends Link {


@override
  Stream<Response> request(
    Request request, [
    NextLink? forward,
  ]) {
    Stream<Response> response = forward!(request).map((Response fetchResult) {
      final ioStreamedResponse =
          fetchResult.context.entry<HttpLinkResponseContext>();
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Request: " + request.toString());
        print("Response:" + (ioStreamedResponse?.toString() ?? "null"));
      }
      return fetchResult;
    }).handleError((error) {
      // throw error;
    });

    return response;
  }

  LoggerLink();
}
```

you can create instance of this link

```
final _loggerLink = LoggerLink() ;
```

then you will concat it in your client

```
client = ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient>(GraphQLClient(
      link: _loggerLink.concat(httpLink),
      cache: GraphQLCache(),
      defaultPolicies: DefaultPolicies(
        watchQuery: Policies(fetch: FetchPolicy.networkOnly),
        query: Policies(fetch: FetchPolicy.networkOnly),
        mutate: Policies(fetch: FetchPolicy.networkOnly),
      ),
    ));
```

note that

```
httpLink
```

is your actual link

Comment: How can I read the HttpLink url from the LoggerLink